# Sacar un Alert() con jquery y animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

El ejercicio es el siguiente, tengo una carrera de coches en la que tienen que llegar a la meta al llegar a unos px que le pongo yo, por ejemplo en este caso los coches llegan hasta 850px y yo quiero que cuando uno llegue a 500px salte un alert con el ganador pero soy incapaz de meterle un if que funcione.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="boton1">Start Animation</button>
    <img id="hola" src="https://i.blogs.es/326a59/ferrari/1366_2000.jpeg"
        style="width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute">
    <img id="hola1" src="https://www.bixpe.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/conduccin_coche_empresa-510x320.png"
        style="width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;top: 250px;">
    <script>
        let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000 + 1);
        let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000 + 1);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#boton1").click(function () {
                $("#hola").animate({ left: '850px' }, a, 'linear');
                $("#hola1").animate({ left: '850px' }, b, 'linear');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es necesario hacer antes de que se complete la animación? Hay forma de hacer algo cuando se complete la animación pero antes, es algo dificil

Comment: Perdona no contestar antes se me paso, hay que hacerlo al final de la animación, se supone que es una carrera de coches y cuando lleguen al final lo metería en un array para hacer el podio, pero no se como hacer parra que al llegar al final se muestre un alert, por decir algo ese alert seria la orden para meter el coche en  un array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separado por coma, se puede agregar una función a la animación; y dentro de esa función se puede hacer lo que sea:

```
$("#hola1").animate({

   left: "850px"

}, b, 'linear', function() {

   // alert()

});
```

El ejemplo está en la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/animate/). El `this` indica al botón, no a las imagenes

```html
    
<button id="boton1">Start Animation</button>
<img id="hola" src="https://i.blogs.es/326a59/ferrari/1366_2000.jpeg" style="width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute"> 
<img id="hola1" src="https://www.bixpe.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/conduccin_coche_empresa-510x320.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;top: 250px;"> 
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000 + 1);
let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000 + 1); 

$(document).ready( function() { 

$("#boton1").on("click", function() { 
    
    $("#hola").animate({ 
        
        left: '850px'
    
    }, a, 'linear', function() {
    
     //alert("llego el primero")
     $(this).after( "<div>Llego el primero</div>" );
        
    });
    
    
    $("#hola1").animate({ 
        
        left: '850px' 
    
    }, b, 'linear', function() {

     //alert("llego el dos")
        $(this).after( "<div>Ganó el segundo</div>" );
        
    });
    
    }); 
 

});
</script>
```